# Multiple SQL Databases with EF - Good or Bad design?

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework

Currently we have a large in house platform that makes use of a number of different SQL databases (all on the same server).  We have always created new databases where we feel that the data is quite different/independant from what we are storing in the other databases.  With this approach we have ended up having a number of different databases (most have 30-50+ tables), but inevitably there is always some connections required between them.

As we are using Entity Framework, any cross database queries are proving a real pain, we have tried a number of different approaches and I personally feel that the main problem is that EF just doesn't really work across multiple databases.

While I know that the answer is often "it depends" I'm interested in peoples ideas or views on this so really the question is

1. Should we combine all of our seperate databases into one large database?
2. Were correct to have split our data into different databases (even if EF doesn't work well with it)?

Comment: Sorry, but...it depends. ;) How large is large? How many tables are you dealing with in each database? How many in all? You could always define views in each database that call out to the other databases and build entities that use them.

Comment: I normally suggest not to separate data unless this is very little to no cross communication.  Usually schema's are more then adequate to segment data.

Comment: You could experiment with using updatable views on "MainDatabase", that has views written to the other databases.  I don't know if EF plays nicely with updatable views.  I think most people write stored procedures to work with EF if using updatable-views.  But its an idea that you might want to look into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How large a database are you talking about? How many tables / how many GBs? What is the type of data that goes in?

The answer as you guessed is most likely "It depends". But here I'd say no, splitting is probably not a right choice.
If you are having to do cross database queries, most likely the data split is not correct. It might be better to split across databases in certain scenarios where the data is independent - like transactional and reporting, for example (but of course that requires a data sync from one to the other).

Have you considered separating the data in same database, but residing on different schema? That is what is usually done.

Comment: The databases are not that large 5-10GB for the more data heavy ones, and less than 1GB for the others.  The data heavy ones tend to store market data series e.g. DateTime and Value

Comment: Lots of tables in use though (30-50) per db

Comment: I'd definitely go with schemas - much easier to manage, keep in sync across environments. Unless you DB size goes to 100s of GBs (even then it could be fine), you should try to move to a single DB to make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

You say

> where we feel that the data is quite different/independant from what we are storing in the other databases

and then

> cross database queries are proving a real pain

If you're having to do many cross-database queries, then it's likely that the data isn't quite as independent as you thought, in which case it might make more sense to merge the databases.

On the other hand, if your cross-database queries are rare, then it might be ok. Without knowing the details of your domain model and what you've got in each database, it's hard to say. Examine the cases where you're making these cross-database queries, and look at *why* you're making them, and *how often* that happens. If it's important or frequent, then consider merging. If it's rare, or not performance-critical, or the hassle of merging the database far outweighs the hassle of writing these few cross-database queries, then it's probably fine. Be careful with that last point though - it might be easier to leave the databases separate *now*, but you may come across something in the future that would be much easier on a merged database. Have another look at what sorts of data you're storing in these databases and work out a list of all the scenarios where you might need cross-database querying. Then look at each of those scenarios and decide how likely it is to happen, and how much of a problem it'll cause if you don't merge the database. That should help you decide whether to merge.

If you do decide to merge, do it as soon as you can. Every day that passes without that merge is a day where people are writing code that'll have to be refactored when you do get around to merging. The sooner you do it, the easier it'll be.